# What is difference between GeometryReader and GeometryProxy in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

As per Apple,

**GeometryReader
A container view that defines its content as a function of its own size and coordinate space.**

**GeometryProxy:
A proxy for access to the size and coordinate space (for anchor resolution) of the container view.**

I am trying to understand when to use GeometryReader and when to use GeometryProxy? I did google but didn't see any post coming up in results. So I am asking here so that new developers like me can use it for reference.

Answer (score 17):

**GeometryReader**

> SwiftUI’s GeometryReader allows us to determine the size and
>   coordinates of views as a function of its own size and coordinates.

You can use a `GeometryReader` like this:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    SomeView()
        .offset(x: geometry.size.width / 2)
}
```

**GeometryProxy**

The closure variable (`geometry`) in the code above is of type `GeometryProxy`. This struct provides us with the following information:

```
public var size: CGSize { get }
public var safeAreaInsets: EdgeInsets { get }
public func frame(in coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace) -> CGRect
public subscript<T>(anchor: Anchor<T>) -> T where T : Equatable { get }
```

Basically a `GeometryReader` *reads* the view (its size, coordinates etc.) and returns a `GeometryProxy` struct from which you can access all the information.

Useful links:

- [Understanding frames and coordinates inside GeometryReader](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/understanding-frames-and-coordinates-inside-geometryreader)
- [GeometryReader to the Rescue](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/)
- [Anchor preferences in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/18/anchor-preferences-in-swiftui/)